# c++ Unhandled exception: System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c++

i'm trying to get process name from Win32_Processor soo i create function ProcessNameInfo.

my code is :

```
void ProcessNameInfo(string nameoption, String^ hardwareClass, String^ propertyNname)
{
    ManagementObjectSearcher^ searcher = gcnew ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM " + hardwareClass);
    ManagementObjectCollection^ collection = searcher->Get();

    for each (ManagementObject^ object in collection)
    {

        String ^ s = object[propertyNname]->ToString();
        CString str3(s);
        const TCHAR* x = (LPCTSTR)str3;

        char szString[MAX_LENGTH];
        size_t nNumCharConverted;
        wcstombs_s(&nNumCharConverted, szString, MAX_LENGTH,
            x, MAX_LENGTH);

        std::string HardwareInfo = szString;
        std::transform(HardwareInfo.begin(), HardwareInfo.end(), HardwareInfo.begin(), [](char ch) {
            return ch == ' ' ? '_' : ch;
        });

        file << "\"" << nameoption << "\": \"" << HardwareInfo << "\"," << endl;
    }

}
```

in the main i call this function like this :

ProcessNameInfo("Processor", "Win32_Processor", "Name");

for some devices it's working but in another devices i get error Unhandled exception:

```
System.NullReferenceException object reference not set to an instance of an object in ProcessNameInfo(basic_string<char\,std::char_traites<char>\,std::allocator<char> >* nameoption, String hardwareClass, String propertyNname) in main() _mainCRTStartup()
```

Comment: It happens when the device does not returns anything but null only to the function.

Comment: There's a few possible things that could throw that exception, you'll have to debug to find which one exactly is null. Also this question should be tagged accordingly (I'm guessing this is C++/CLI?)

Comment: @UnholySheep  i have visual studio only in my laptop and it's working fine. in client machine i execute just the exe and i get error, i can't debug to find exactly which line is null

Comment: You should add logging and/or generate a debuggable mini-dump file from clients that have the issue. There's always ways to debug applications "in the wild"

Comment: Test the code with another property that *is* null on your machine.  Like "Version".  [Use this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8572).